# find and find next function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am currently trying to finish this function that checks for values on another sheet but currently only checks for the first value only and not checking for the duplicates.

sheet1 functions

```
Function Checkcollipotecaassente(row As Range)
   Dim ndg As String
   Dim loanid As String
   Dim rowindex As Integer
   ndg = extrapolatendg(row)
   rowindex = Sheet6.findrownumberndg(ndg)
   loanid = Sheet6.getloanid(rowindex)

   If Sheet7.findrownumberloan(loanid) = True Then
            If Sheet6.CheckDuplicate(ndg) = True Then
               Do
                rowindex = Sheet6.Findrownumberdg2(rowindex)
                loanid = Sheet6.getloanid(rowindex)
                Loop Until Sheet7.findrownumberloan(loanid) = False
           End If

       Checkcollipotecaassente = True
   Else
       Checkcollipotecaassente = False
   End If
End Function
```

sheet6 functions

```
Function CheckDuplicate(extrapolatendg As String) As Boolean

    Set foundcell = Range("B:B").Find(extrapolatendg, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If foundcell Is Nothing Then
        CheckDuplicate = False
    Else
        adrFirst = foundcell.Address
        Set foundcell = Sheet6.Range("B:B").FindNext(foundcell)
        If foundcell.Address = adrFirst Then
            CheckDuplicate = False
        Else
            CheckDuplicate = True
        End If
    End If

End Function
Function Findrownumberdg2(findrownumberndg As Integer)

        adrFirst = foundcell.Address
        Set foundcell = Sheet6.Range("B:B").FindNext(foundcell)
        If foundcell.Address = adrFirst Then
            Findrownumberdg2 = 0
        Else
            Findrownumberdg2 = foundcell.row
        End If


End Function
Function findrownumberndg(extrapolatendg As String) As Integer


Set foundcell = Range("B:B").Find(extrapolatendg, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then

 findrownumberndg = foundcell.row


Else

findrownumberndg = 0

End If

End Function
```

So once the findrownumberndg finds the row number on sheet6 and the checkduplicate function finds duplicates i need the findrownumberndg2 to loop until the the findrownumberloan returns a false but it doesnt.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `do while findrownumberloan = True ... Loop`. Ill have a closer look later, but that should work in your case

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext